# How to Raise an Event when the content of a container (i.e. Grid) was fully rendered in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events

**Well**, yes, It's very annoying not to know when all the content of a Grid was rendered...

I can't do it with .IsVisibilityChanged because It doesn't affect to the content...

And, `OnContentRendered(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnContentRendered(e)` is only called the first time...

So what can I do?

I only want to Raise an event when the content was fully rendered.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: `It's very annoying..` - no it's not. You're doing everything in a totally wrong way and that's why you're constantly fighting against the framework. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: Very useful recommendation of @HighCore as always, some things and modals that could be hard to keep in mind for a WinForms developer (like the OP and me)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Loaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx) some explanation.